# Match to most match words with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would like to write a LINQ query that will return records with the most matched words ordered by the number of words matched. and the words don't have to be in order

input:

```
"word3 word2"
```

string array:

```
"word1 word2 word3 word4 word5"
"word1 word2"
"word4 word5"
"word1 word4 word5"
```

the output would be

```
"word1 word2 word3 word4 word5"
"word1 word2"
```

Is this doable with LINQ?

Comment: Have you tried anything or simply want us to do your job/homework?

Comment: i did try spiting the input into a string array and then where contains the input array. but stuck on the ordered by the number of words matched part

Comment: any tips on how to write this?

Comment: Edit your question with what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with Linq.

The example:

```
var wantedWords = "word3 word2".Split();
var strings = new List<string>
{
    "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5",
    "word1 word2",
    "word4 word5",
    "word1 word4 word5"
};
var result = from s in strings
             let words = s.Split()
             select new
             {
                 String = s,
                 MatchedCount = wantedWords.Count(ww => words.Contains(ww))
             } into e
             where e.MatchedCount > 0
             orderby e.MatchedCount descending
             select e.String;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that a combination of `Linq` and `Regex` did the job.  Take the input, and turn it into a pattern to use in the `Where()` `Linq`.

In this example, the input is turned into the pattern of

```
"word3|word2"
```

We use that to find lines in the array that have word3 OR (The pipe character means OR in `Regex`) word2.

```
string input = "word3 word2";
string[] array = 
{
    "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5",
    "word1 word2",
    "word4 word5",
    "word1 word4 word5"
};

string pattern = input.Replace(" ", "|");
List<string> results = array.Where(a => Regex.Match(a, pattern).Success).ToList();
results.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Results:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
word1 word2
```